# How random.nextBytes(bytes) generates the bytes after we have seed

Tags: java, security, random

I know that if we declare:

```
SecureRandom random=new SecureRandom();
```

It initializes the default algorithm to generate random number is `NativePRNG` which reads `/dev/random` to generate the truly random `seed`. Now we have truly random `seed` which is 160 bit size, but i am confused what happens when we call `random.nextBytes(bytes);`. How it generates `bytes` from the `seed`,does it again read the `/dev/random` or something else.

Thanks.

**N.B.:**  *i am looking for default behavior in java 7 in linux/MAC box.*

Answer (score 1):

From the Java API docs:

> Many SecureRandom implementations are in the form of a pseudo-random
>   number generator (PRNG), which means they use a deterministic
>   algorithm to produce a pseudo-random sequence from a true random seed.
>   Other implementations may produce true random numbers, and yet others
>   may use a combination of both techniques.

So whether `nextBytes(bytes)` returns true random bytes from `/dev/random` or whether it returns pseudo-random numbers generated from the true random seed depends. The second case means that using the initially random seed, a deterministic but seemingly random (and hence, pseudo-random) number sequence is generated by any calls to the `SecureRandom`.

Java 7 allows for a configurable PRNG source to be specified, but on Linux the default one is `NativePRNG` and on Windows `SHA1PRNG`. You can also specify `SHA1PRNG` on Linux, but the default option of `NativePRNG` is better. The `SHA1PRNG` generates PRNG bits and bytes through the use of SHA1. On Linux (and possibly other Unixes, where the mechanism is "`NativePRNG`"), the algorithm reads from `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom`, so as long as there is enough entropy available through either of those. For the sake of completeness, from the Linux man page on `random`:

> A read from the /dev/urandom device will not block waiting for more
>   entropy. As a result, if there is not sufficient entropy in the
>   entropy pool, the returned values are theoretically vulnerable to a
>   cryptographic attack on the algorithms used by the driver.

**Therefore, on Linux at least, your `SecureRandom` will have a certain amount of true random output** until `/dev/random` blocks due to a shortage of entropy, **however if you request too many random bits, they will eventually start being generated by the underlying `/dev/urandom` machinery, which may use SHA1 or some other cryptographic hashing algorithm in a PRNG**.

*It's best to create a `SecureRandom` without specifying any explicit seed yourself*, as it will seed itself (by default via `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` for the `NativePRNG` on Linux) with a good seed. Calling `nextBytes(bytes)` every few minutes, even for a large amount of bytes, is not bound to be an issue in almost any circumstance. Even if you are using the `NativePRNG` and it resorts to getting pseudo-random bytes from `/dev/urandom` via something like SHA-1, the output of this will still be extremely difficult to predict.

If you are asking for gigabytes of randomness, it might be good to re-seed, either using some output from the `SecureRandom` itself or by providing your own seed. Note that it should be safe providing any kind of seed to `setSeed()`, as `SecureRandom` internally augments the current seed by feeding the seed you provide and the previous seed to something like SHA-1 or another cryptographic hashing algorithm. However, it is still best to create the initial `SecureRandom` without giving your own seed.

Comment: Can you tell me about the default behavior of java 7 in linux box.

Comment: What is the best way to use SecureRandom? Crate the an instance of SecureRandom and do nextBytes? or some thing else. I am calling nextBytes in every 5 minutes. Will it have some issues?

Comment: Yes, create an instance (without specifying your own seed!) and call the nextBytes(). You won't really have any issues with predictability and repeating of the byte outputs.